# Android TimePicker issues

Tags: android, dialog, datetimepicker, timepicker, timepickerdialog

On Android I set an EditText with a TimePicker Dialog. Default Time is now, but using TimePicker time shuld change.

I have three issues:

1) Selecting another time, sometimes displayng time on EditText not change;

2) If I tip on TimePicker and choose the same time, it change of +12h ( for example now is 09.35 but it display 21.35 );

3) If I choose an hour >= 17.00 I got an exception:

```
07-19 11:47:17.574 16224-16224/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 16224
                                                                        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=17; index=18
                                                                            at java.util.Calendar.set(Calendar.java:1122)
                                                                            at com.example.myapp.activities.MyActivity$9.onTimeSet(MyActivity.java:513)
                                                                            at android.app.TimePickerDialog.onClick(TimePickerDialog.java:133)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:160)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5376)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

This is my TimePicker function:

```
// TimePicker settings
public void setTimeFields(final EditText editText) {
    // Calendar instance
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // TimePicker definition
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            calendar.set(hourOfDay, minute);
            editText.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ITALIAN).format(calendar.getTime()));
        }
    }, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), DateFormat.is24HourFormat(this));
    // Show dialog
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```

And here my editext definition:

```
etxTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxTime);
etxTime.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
etxTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ITALIAN).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
etxTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) { setTimeFields(etxTime); } });
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Show Date dialog
            showDialog(Date_id);
        }
    });
    time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Show time dialog
            showDialog(Time_id);
        }
    });
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    // Get the calander
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    // From calander get the year, month, day, hour, minute
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    switch (id) {
        case Date_id:

            // Open the datepicker dialog
            return new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, date_listener, year,
                    month, day);
        case Time_id:

            // Open the timepicker dialog
            return new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, time_listener, hour,
                    minute, false);

    }
    return null;
}

// Date picker dialog
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date_listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // store the data in one string and set it to text
        String date1 = String.valueOf(month) + "/" + String.valueOf(day)
                + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
        set_date.setText(date1);
    }
};
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener time_listener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
        // store the data in one string and set it to text
        String time1 = String.valueOf(hour) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute);
        set_time.setText(time1);
    }
};
```

> where "date" , "time" are buttons and "set_date", "set_time" are editTexts in this case.

Comment: As your suggestion I change
'calendar.set(hourOfDay, minute);
editText.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm",Locale.ITALIAN).format(calendar.getTime()));
'
to
'calendar.set(hourOfDay, minute);
editText.setText( String.valueOf(hourOfDay) + ":" + String.valueOf(minute));
'
And this solve issues 1) and 2) for me but 3) persist.
So I delete the line 'calendar.set(hourOfDay, minute);' and it works properly.
Thanks for advice.
Anyway, why 'calendar.set(hourOfDay, minute);' create java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ?

Comment: i aslo don't know the why it's throwing exception. Anyways please accept my answer as correct if you think my solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The third issue you're describing occurs because the parameters [Calendar.set(int, int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int)) are not the hour and minute, but the [field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.ALL_STYLES) and value to set.  If you check the table in the link you'll see the max int value of this field is 17. So your code should be as follows:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    editText.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.ITALIAN).format(calendar.getTime()));
}
```